# Where to store .properties files for Java?

Tags: java

The [Java tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html) on using properties talks about how to use the Properties class.  In the tutorial it shows the properties being written to a file called "defaultProperties".  So what is a good name and location for the properties file?

I usually write one of two java applications: a system utility or a user program.  I think most system utilities would have a file in `/etc/myfile.properties` and most user programs would create a `~/.myfile.properties`.  However, these paths would not work in Windows.  Is there a more generic way of defining these details to make the code platform independent?

Comment: Take a look at this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/966029

Comment: The short answer to your final question is "no". Windows doesn't really have good places to keep config files in quite the same way as unix does, because it's less file-oriented. That's precisely why the preferences API was invented. Which is a shame, i admit, but there you go.

Answer (score 8):

If you are talking about keeping external property file  to configure your app then 
I would suggest

```
System.getProperty("user.home")+File.separator+ "yourappname"+File.separator+"name.properties"
```

of if you are talking about property file placed internal to your project keep it in `default package`.

**OR**

other options are using XML file, or [`Preference`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html)

Comment: This seems doable.  Is there a platform-independent equivalent to `/etc`?  I'm not even sure what that would map to in Windows since the registry is typically used for that info.

Comment: `System.getProperty("user.home")` is platform independent, for linux it would be /home/userName/ , for windows it would be `c:\\Documents and Settings\\userName\\ `

Comment: life.java: unexpectedly, on Windows, it's not C:\Documents and Settings\userName, it's something like C:\WINNT\Profiles\userName. See http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4162112 and friends. However, for User1's purposes, this is probably better.

Comment: @Tom what ever the place it may be it is user's home at the end java will resolve it and it will be platform independent

Answer (score 7):

In this case I would use the `Preferences` API instead of `Properties`.

`Preferences` allows you to store/retrieve user and system settings and automatically handles the persistence for you. The persistence is platform specific; for Windows it uses the registry and for Unix it uses hidden files.

Comment: I like this idea and I think it would work for most projects.  However, sometimes I want a configuration file exposed that the user can tweak outside of the application.  Is there a way to make the `Preferences` API work that way?

Comment: If you want a config file that the user can tweak, use `Properties`.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of alternate solutions:

- Read the property file from the classpath
- Pass the path to the property file as a startup argument to the application

Reading it from the classpath gives you flexibility, since you can then include it in the jar itself or specify it when the application starts.

Answer (score 0):

If your are bundling the props file as part of the app and is for read-only then put it in jar file. If you have to also update it then make it available through file:/// url and pass the file path as a JVM (-DfileUrl=...) argument.

Look at this post on how to read the props file from a JAR in classpath: [Reading properties file from JAR directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301373/reading-properties-file-from-jar-directory)

Answer (score 0):

Using jndi is a good solution. Runtime config via admin console of webserver. Webapp will pickup changes as soon as you get a property, You don't have to restart the application.