# how to save file app data folder

Tags: java

Im working on a project and I need the program to store some of the property files and some text files.
How could I save a file in the appdata folder on windows in java also what would be the linux equivalent of appdat?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please take a look at - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4670815/where-to-store-properties-files-for-java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Save the file to `System.getenv("APPDATA")`

[AppData Java Docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getenv%28java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a sub-directory of `user.home` to store the data.